# Braintree: Can the trial periods of subscriptions be changed?

Tags: braintree

When changing a subscription to be on a new plan, I noticed that the trial period did not change to match the new plan. I also have not been able to find a way to change the trial period in the [docs for subscription.update](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/subscription/update/node)

Is it possible to change the trial period of a subscription after it has been created?

Comment: Braintree's API allows you to accept payment over the web and create recurring payment plans programmatically. Its a question about how to implement Braintree's API.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError What? O_o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact our [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) team.</sub>

When changing a subscription to be on a new plan, you cannot update the trial period on the subscription. The trial period is expected to be at the beginning of a subscription. I would suggest creating a new subscription with the new plan and the same payment_method_token.